# Phpmyadmin not creating new column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to create a new column for a database table in my phpmyadmin however i keep getting this below. Also i notice that i cant change the move column field in the dropdown its all grey

The preview is

```
ALTER TABLE `jobs` ADD `job_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER ;
```

**I get this error shortly after**

```
   Notice in ./libraries/classes/CreateAddField.php#152
 Undefined index: after_field

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/CreateAddField.php#113: PhpMyAdmin\CreateAddField->setColumnCreationStatementSuffix(
integer 0,
integer -1,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/classes/CreateAddField.php#302: PhpMyAdmin\CreateAddField->buildColumnCreationStatement(
integer 1,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/classes/CreateAddField.php#536: PhpMyAdmin\CreateAddField->getColumnCreationStatements(boolean false)
./tbl_addfield.php#69: PhpMyAdmin\CreateAddField->tryColumnCreationQuery(
```

Comment: AFTER what exactly?

Comment: @Omar T, ALTER TABLE `jobs` ADD `job_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER   column_name. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add column Name after which you want to add it

```
ALTER TABLE `jobs` ADD `job_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER yourcolumnName
```